# How to Use Nvarchar2 Column in Parameterized SQL Query for Unicode Characters?

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, plsql

Hi guyz i have a problem with Nvarchar2 column in Oracle 10g, basically i want to insert Unicode characters in DB table at run-time, i google it for this and find N prefix method to insert or update Unicode characters in Nvarchar2 column like below:

> `Insert into nvarchar_test (c_nvarchar) VALUES (N'اب ج قر');`

Characters i used to insert above are URDU language characters, above statement is working perfectly, but my requirement is that i want to pass URDU Unicode characters at run-time as variable instead of hard-coded them i tried below PL-SQL code for this:

```
Declare     
  urdu_characters Nvarchar2 (500);    
Begin    
  urdu_characters := 'اب ج';    
  Insert into nvarchar_test (c_nvarchar) VALUES (N urdu_characters);    
End;
```

As you see above code is not correct because i'm not able to use N Prefix with variable and don't know how i will i do kindly help me to sort out this issue.

Thank You !

Answer (score 2):

From your initial question: `N` changes the string constant, so use it at declaration time. Here is how you must go:

```
Declare     
  urdu_characters Nvarchar2 (500);    
Begin    
  urdu_characters := N'اب ج';    
  Insert into nvarchar_test (c_nvarchar) VALUES (urdu_characters);    
End;
```

But `N'اب ج'` is (more or less) equivalent to `CAST('اب ج' AS NVARCHAR2(..))`. A possibility to include urdu chars in a pl would be to use the `ASCIISTR(..)` function:

```
Declare     
  urdu_characters Nvarchar2 (500);    
Begin    
  urdu_characters := 'اب ج';    
  Insert into nvarchar_test (c_nvarchar) VALUES (ASCIISTR(urdu_characters));    
End;
```

Comment: problem is still same if i want to change the value of variable urdu_characters from 'ا ب ج' to ' ق ت د' how i deal this N Prefix work with single quote's e.g **N'  '** so my question is how we pass the new value to urdu_characters variable , i wrote a parameterized procedure which get this Unicode characters at run-time and than i use them in query which is in this procedure   ?

Comment: @ahad if you are sending the parameter from a program, you will need to use oracle driver and set the parameter as `OracleDbType.NVarchar2` for it to work properly.